# How to get live GPU clock speed on steam games as overlay?

Tags: drivers, steam, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I would like to get gpu clock rates while playing steam games like msi afterburner's osd shows. My concern is only about getting clock rates only as I am working on project to get full gpu speed on games but there is no way to monitor. I have integrated vega 8 gpu (AMD ryzen 2500u). AMDuProf is correctly showing clock rates of GPU but there is no overlay available on that and it cannot be opened while playing games it is just inconvenient and affects GPU clocks. It basically uses AMDuProfDriver, I want to know if there is something that can use similar method to get GPU clock rates as overlay while playing games.

GLXOSD not working. lm-sensors not working.
GALLIUM_HUD not showing clocks.